# Why does Arrays.sort take Object[] rather than Comparable[]?

Tags: java, interface, casting, comparable

I was wondering why the sort method of the Arrays class is asking for a parameter of type Object[].  Why the parameter is not of type Comparable[]. If you don't pass a Comparable[] it's generating a ClassCastException.

Why ... **public static void sort(Object[] a)** and not **public static void sort(Comparable[] a)** ?
Thanks

Comment: You have same situation at other places in the Java api, e.g. the ObjectOutputStream which expects an Object implementing Serializable. I guess, the developers tried to prevent us from doing unecessary casts.

Comment: Back in the day, there were multiple people implementing JDK's, not just Sun. Implementations of the class may have desired the Comparable, but allowed any deterministic, stable sort. (Hypothetically speaking)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the second form would require a reallocation of the array. Even if you know that your array contains only comparables, you cannot just cast it to Comparable[] if the original type was Object[], since the array type does not match.

You can do:

```
Object[] arr = new String[0];
String[] sarr = (String[]) arr;
```

But you can't do:

```
Object[] arr = new Object[0];
String[] sarr = (String[]) arr;
```

So it's premature optimization :)

Comment: "you cannot just cast it to Comparable[] if the original type was Object[]" - but *why should I expect* to be able to call it with an `Object[]`? If it's an intentional design constraint of the program that the array should only contain `Comparable`s, why wouldn't I create and use a `Comparable[]` in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

Otherwise you can't pass `Object[]` in.

Comment: @BalusC Is there ever a situation where you would pass to sort an array of Objects that you didn't know were all implementing `Comparable`?  Any use of the sort method will be by objects that are `Comparable`.  Seems like the only reason for accepting `Object[]` is that `Object` is used more frequently and is more familiar, and like ZeissS said, otherwise we would have to cast.

Comment: There are still a lot of `toArray()` like methods in Java API which returns `Object[]`.

Comment: They could be implementing `Comparator<T>`, which is similar, but not the same as `Comparable<T>`