providing method of interface instead of implementing interface in java
I am reading about interfaces in Java. It is mentioned that we have to implement compareTo method for calling "sort" on ArrayList Container, for example Employee class should implement Comparable Interface.
Later it is explained why can't the Employee class simply provide "compareTo" method without implementing Comparable interface?  The reason for interfaces is that Java programming is strongly typed. When making a method call, the compiler needs to be able to check that the method actually exist.
So I am expecting compile time error when I don't implement "Comparable interface and using Arrays.sort method, but I am not observing compile error, instead getting runtime error.  Kindly explain why compile time error is not shown in above scenario
Below is code snippet
package com.vrk.inheritance;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Employee
{
   private String name;
   private double salary;
   private LocalDate hireDay;

   public Employee(String name, double salary, int year, int month, int day)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.salary = salary;
      hireDay = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
   }

   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

   public double getSalary()
   {
      return salary;
   }

   public LocalDate getHireDay()
   {
      return hireDay;
   }

   public void raiseSalary(double byPercent)
   {
      double raise = salary * byPercent / 100;
      salary += raise;
   }
   
   /*public int compareTo(Object otherObject) {
       System.out.println("Employee compareTo called");
       return 0;
   }*/
   
   /**
    * equalTo function in employee. Created on 8th Sep 2024
    * @param another object to compare to this object
    */
   public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
       // quick test to check if objects are identical
       if ( this == otherObject) return true;
       
       // must return false if the explicit parameter is null
       if(otherObject == null) return false;
       
       // if the classes don't match, they can't be equal
       if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass()) return false;
       
       // now we know otherObject is a non-null Employee
       var other = (Employee) otherObject;
       
       // test whether the fields have identical value
       // Not sure in my setup below line is not working, but online compiler it is working. 
       // java.util.Objects.equals(this.hireDay, other.hireDay);
        return true;
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       var staff = new Employee[3];

       // fill the staff array with Manager and Employee objects
       staff[0] = new Employee("Harry Hacker", 50000, 1989, 10, 1);
       staff[1] = new Employee("Tommy Tester", 40000, 1990, 3, 15);
       staff[1] = new Employee("Ravi Tester", 60000, 1999, 4, 16);
       Arrays.sort(staff);
   }
}


The things you are reading are very wrong. This is not answerable because the premise is false.

The Arrays#sort(Object[]) method takes an Object[]. That's why your code compiles. However, at run-time you will get a ClassCastException. In an ideal world, the method would be defined as <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(T[] array) to help with compile-time validation, but the method was written before generics.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2246615/5133585

If you look at the documentation for Arrays.sort, you'll see it doesn't use generics at all; it just takes an Object[]. That's why you don't get a compilation error.
This is for historical reasons: the method was written before Java introduced generics.

Thanks for response. @yshavit, why do we have to implement interface if we have to able to call method which is implemented in class.

Because otherwise the method would have to do some non-trivial reflection. It's much easier, and as you pointed out much more in keeping with Java's philosophy of type systems, to just cast the Object to Comparable. Java does not implement duck typing, essentially as a matter of principle.
